# how to use cin.getline() for more than one line of text input

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an array of characters and then use cin.getline() to store input from the user which is more than one line.

I know I can do this easily using vectors and string class but I need to do it using C-style.

```
int main (){
int size;
cout << "Please enter how many character you want to type: ";
cin >> size;
cin.ignore();
char array[size];

 while (cin.getline(array,size))
    {

        cin.getline(array,size);

    }
cout << array;

}
```

I couldn't figure out how can I keep iterating even though when the user hit enter and how to let the user stop it at any time.

This is how I slove it using Vectors and string

```
while ( getline (cin,input) ) {

        if ( input == "quit" ) {
        break;
        }
        container.push_back( input );
    }
```

I still need to do it as I have mentioned above. Any hints would be highly appreciated

> Edit:

I want my program to perform like the one I wrote using different libraries which is not allowed in this task.

Read text from keyboard/file. sort each line alphabetically. print them on screen and save them in file.

My complete previous program that does this:

using namespace std;

class text_handling{
public:

```
void keyboard_input (){

    string input;
    vector< string > container;
    vector< int > int_container;
    cout << "Pleas enter your text, Enter \"quit\" to exit: \n" ;
    while ( getline (cin,input) ) {

        if ( input == "quit" ) {
        break;
        }
        container.push_back( input );
    }

    cout << "#####################################"<<endl ;
    cout << "\nOriginal order of the text:"<<endl ;
    for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), [](const string& s) { cout << s << endl; } );

    sort( container.begin(), container.end() );

    cout << "#####################################"<<endl ;
    cout << "\nSorted order of the text:" << endl;
    for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), [](const string& s) { cout << s << endl; } );

    ofstream output_file("./example.txt");
    ostream_iterator<string> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    copy(container.begin(), container.end(), output_iterator);
    cout << "#####################################"<<endl ;
    cout << "Your file has been updated" << endl;
}


void file_input (){

    ifstream output_file("./example.txt");
    vector<string> container;
    string input;
    while(getline (output_file,input)){

    container.push_back(input);
    }

    for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), [](const string& s) { cout << s << endl; } );

}
```

};
int main(){

```
text_handling obj;
int x;
cout << "Please enter 1 if you want to write text using keyboard , Press any key to load text from file" << endl;
cin >> x;
if (x==1){
obj.keyboard_input();
}
else{
int start_s=clock();
obj.file_input();   
int stop_s=clock();
cout << "time: " << (stop_s-start_s)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << endl;
}
```

}

I need to do the same thing but without using vectors or string or algorithm classes. Just c-style.

My idea was to create a char array and use `cin.getline()` to read all the lines that the user enter. then try to loop through them and sort them out somehow and store them. I got stuck with the first step as you can see in my question above

Comment: You're going to have to do all the work you were leveraging from `vector` and `string`. In short, do a `strcmp` for "quit" to exit, otherwise append the data you read to whatever variable you're using to store your result.  You could probably be sneaky with `realloc` and pointer offsets if you don't want to manage variables for the final result and what you're reading.

Comment: @StephenNewell thank you for your response. I actually need the array data for some sorting tasks. I will start by checking the "strcmp" to see where I can go from there. thanks for the hint

Comment: Unfortunately is it illegal to create arrays like that using a size given at runtime. Some compilers allow it as a non-standard extension. But it is not officially legal `C++`.

Comment: So where are you planning on storing the input lines?

Comment: @Galik I know it's not the best way to use an array. After storing them in a char array I want to sort them and then save them in a file.

Comment: @Kashan: you do know you can sort characters in a `std::string` too?  E.g. `std::sort(mystring.begin(), mystring.end());`, optinally with a third argument specifying how to sort (for example,  if you wanted a case insensitive sort, or letters to be sorted ahead of numbers)....

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks for your reply. I have done that already which is way easier and simple. But the task to do it now with classical C-style without using algorithm or string classes.

Comment: Sure - as a tip for phrasing questions/responses on S.O. - it helps to say your assignment/homework requires that, otherwise it's unclear whether you just didn't know it was possible to sort `std::string` content.  All good.  Just be careful - `strcmp(buffer, "abc") == 0` is how to check for equality - many people forget the `== 0`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Sorry man, my bad. I should have mentioned that. However, sorting is not my main question here. the question is to read and store the user input text. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Question's still not very clear.  Is it enough to store the line into your `char array[size];`, process it and throw it away, or is your problem keeping the lines around longer so you can use all the lines after reading the file?  If the latter, you might want to use `strdup()` (C-style allocation) or `new[]` & `copy` to copy each line read, then store the pointers for later use.  You can create an array `char* lines[Max_Lines];`, or learn to use `realloc()` or `new[] / copy / delete[]` to increase the number of lines you can handle at runtime - that's fiddlier.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Could you please check the thread again after the edit. I explained exactly what I want.

Comment: Some things are still unclear.  You say "C style" but you're still using iostreams.  Do you need to use C-style malloc/realloc/free, or C++ style new/delete?  Anyway, for the `char* lines[Max_Lines];` I mention above and C-style allocation, after each `getline` just have `lines[++num_lines] = strdup(array);`  You can then iterate `for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; ++i) std::cout << lines[i] << '\n';` to print the pre-sorted order, and use `qsort` or implement your own sort.